# PHP add space before <a - tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to add a whitespace before every

```
<a
```

in a string with php if there is not already a whitespace.

So this

```
hello world <a
```

should stay as it is

but this

```
hello world<a
```

should become the same as the first example.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\s)<a/', ' <a', $text);
```

should do the trick

The `(?<!\s)` is called a negative look behind, only `<a` that do not have a whitespace before them will be replaced.